# SQL: How to find duplicates across 2 columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

I would like to return either 'duplicate' or 'not duplicate' for values in column A that appear in column B  within the same table. Example below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | duplicate |
| 2 | 4 | not duplicate |
| 5 | 3 | not duplicate |

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ColumnB = t1.ColumnA)
         THEN 'duplicate' ELSE 'not duplicate' END AS ColumnC
FROM yourTable t1;
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach, it will work well for small datasets, but when your dataset is large you want to use a join instead of an inner query).  ie:  This will result in  n+1 queries being run,  1 for the main query and 1 for each record in the table.

Comment: I disagree.  The actual work done either with my approach or a join approach is very similar.  The difference with my answer is that it stops searching as soon as a match is found.  Hence I expect my answer to outperform a join.

Answer (score 1):

Join is solution

```
   SELECT columnA, columnB, case when t2.columnB is not null then 'duplicate' else 'not duplicate' end as columnC
    FROM  table1 t1 left join table1 t2 on t1.columnA = t2.columnB
```

Comment: What happens if a given value in A matches to more than one value in B?

Comment: Yes, multiple row will be return. We can get first by use rank()... But i think it will be good performance than sub query.